# Параметры URL авторизации vk.com

Tags: javascript, php, url, сессия, авторизация

Хочу написать авторизацию на сайте VK(на самом сайте, а не в API и не авторизацию на моем сайте через VK) на PHP. Для этого хочу понять логику авторизации:
Сначала заходим на страницу
https://m.vk.com или https://vk.com
Дальше, если кликнуть на кнопку "Войти", то попадаем на страницу с адресом вида:

```
 https://id.vk.com/auth?v=1.32.0&app_id=7934657&uuid=28c49e86b5&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fm.vk.com%2Flogin&app_settings=W10%3D&action=eyJuYW1lIjoibm9fcGFzc2dvcmRfZmxvdyIsInBhcmFtcyI6eyJ0eXBlIjoic1lnbl9pbiJ9fQ%3D%3D&scheme=bright_light
```

Не выходит разобраться откуда берутся параметры app_id, uuid, action. В куках на предыдущей странице ничего похожего вроде нету, и в теле самой страницы тоже.  Посмотрел в старой библиотеке, которая уже не работает: https://github.com/ivastly/vk-auth , часть параметров для получения страницы бралась как-раз из куков, а часть из тела.

Как отследить какой js(вероятно это делает js) скрипт и в каком месте параметры получает? Потому что js на странице много очень для того чтобы раскуривать вручную всю логику...
Через консоль браузера можно смотреть какие скрипты работают, но не смог разобраться как посмотреть работу в момент редиректа(при нажатии на кнопку "Войти").

Как сгенерировать и правильно отправить параметры для авторизации VK?

Comment: А какая тебе разница что где и как там генерируется? Тебе вообще парпаметры страницы авторизации не должны быть интересны, т.к. это вк генерит фрейм, где пользователь даёт добро на операции. Всё. Твоё дело правильно написать авторизацию по той инструкции, которую предоставляет VK API

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Не понял что за инструкция которую API предоставляет? Т.е. можно авторизоваться в ВК через API не регистрируя приложения,  чтобы получить данные сессии с помощью которых можно обращаться к объектам внутри ВК для обращения к которым требуется быть авторизованным, но для обращения к которым не предусмотрено метода API?  Или ты про что? Ведь данные параметры идут дальше в https://api.vk.com/method/auth.validatePhone?v=5.174&client_id=12345   и, как ожидается, нужны вместе с номером телефона чтобы ВК корректно ответил.

Comment: У вк есть чёткая инструкция как залогинить юзера. Смотри еë. А Всплывающее окно, это то, что сам вк делает для одобрения пользователем прав. Тебе зачем эти данные из урл? ..... А своё приложение регистрируется в ЛК разработчика, где выдаётся как раз app id и прочие ключи

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  У них там вагон всяких авторизаций. И я писал авторизацию пользователя в приложении и авторизацию пользователя на сайте через ВК. https://dev.vk.com/api/access-token/implicit-flow-user    Там получаем access_token и приложение может юзать API от имени пользователя который предоставил права. Мне же нужно получать кусочки видео закрытых настройкой приватности "Доступно только для авторизованных пользователей". Для этого(если я все правильно понимаю) нету метода API. А потому нужна эмуляция стандартной авторизации чтобы под сессией заходить и получать...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вполне возможно что я не понимаю чего-то уж разжуй пож. Может api, при использовании методов для которых нужны соотв. права(например https://dev.vk.com/method/video.get )   куки сессии устанавливают и их можно юзать потом чтобы запрашивать то, что не предусмотрено api или что?

Answer (score 0):

Используй документацию VK Api и авторизацию через Oauth, https://dev.vk.com/api/oauth-parameters, на сайте api генерируется примерный адрес, для взаимодействия. Авторизация будет происходить на сайте vk, тебе будет возвращаться массив json. Потом делай с ним, что хочешь.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Это, на сколько я понимаю, авторизация пользователя в приложении, а не авторизация на сайте. Чтобы расставить все точки... предположим есть страница vk.com/str   причем она 1) Недоступна для неавторизованных пользователей. 2) Не существует метода API с помощью которого можно ее получить(мне нужны кадры видео, но не суть).   Как используя code или token, от того на что ты ссылаешься получить информацию с этой страницы?